# tooltip-enable : How can I make sure that tooltip always open on mousehover?

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I kind of have a situation in which i wanna show a tooltip if the condition met , it does but i want on `mouseenter`. But when i write `tooltip-trigger` with `mouseenter`it does not work.

Here is my condition i want this to become true only on the condition and on `mouseenter`.

```
  <div class="event_field popover-wrapper" popover-placement="bottom-left"
                           uib-popover-template="'searchexp.html'"
                           popover-is-open="cv.isskillSugOpen"
                           popover-enable="{{rowform.$visible && cv.DisablePopUp==false}}"

                           uib-tooltip="{{cv.jumpInReady}}"
                           tooltip-placement="top"
                           tooltip-enable="cv.jumpInReady.length>11"
                           tooltip-is-open="cv.jumpInReady.length>11"

                           >
```

Comment: I removed the tooltip-is-open and i wrote a conditon in tooltip-enable like this tooltip-enable="cv.jumpinReady.length ? true : false"